# port forwarding VBox VMs

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, virtualbox, port-forwarding, openstack

I have an Ubuntu Server 14.04 running VirtualBox with some machines. These machines are OpenStack Fuel installed and I cannot change the NIC interfaces infra ( two hostonly and one NAT ).

One of these machines is running the Fuel Control panel, but accessible only by one of the hostonly interfaces ( 10.20.0.2 ).

My home network is 192.168.25.x. The host machine ( Ubuntu ) external is 192.168.25.25.

Now I have a Windows machine in my home network and need to access the Fuel panel running in the VM (IP 10.20.0.2).

What I need is forward the incomming from hardware 192.168.25.25 interface to the virtualbox hostonly 10.20.0.X VM interface to reach the IP 10.20.0.2.

This is my host ifconfig showing all interfaces:

```
root@AKRAB:~# ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Loopback Local
          inet end.: 127.0.0.1  Masc:255.0.0.0
          endereço inet6: ::1/128 Escopo:Máquina
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:19685 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:19685 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:7674590 (7.6 MB) TX bytes:7674590 (7.6 MB)

vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 0a:00:27:00:00:00
          inet end.: 10.20.0.1  Bcast:10.20.0.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:167 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:22260 (22.2 KB)

vboxnet1  Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 0a:00:27:00:00:01
          inet end.: 172.16.0.254  Bcast:172.16.0.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:1/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:437 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:137886 (137.8 KB)

vboxnet2  Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 0a:00:27:00:00:02
          inet end.: 172.16.1.1  Bcast:172.16.1.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:2/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:464 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:150336 (150.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 00:13:46:94:18:c1
          inet end.: 192.168.25.25  Bcast:192.168.25.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::213:46ff:fe94:18c1/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:2354945 erros:0 descartados:4 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:1237088 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3455421823 (3.4 GB) TX bytes:103231994 (103.2 MB)

root@AKRAB:~#
```

You can see the wlan0 external interface (my home network) and the vboxnet0 hiding the network I want to go to ( 10.20.0.2 ).

All these addresses are static including the target. The port number I want to reach in the VM is 8443 (Mirantis Fuel Dashboard).

Tried this with no success:

```
root@AKRAB:~# iptables -I FORWARD -d 10.20.0.2 -m comment --comment "Accept to forward Fuel DashBoard traffic" -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
root@AKRAB:~# iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8443 -m comment --comment "redirect pkts to virtual machine" -j DNAT --to-destination 10.20.0.2:8443
root@AKRAB:~# iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "NAT the src ip" -d 10.20.0.2 -o vboxnet0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**Results:**

```
root@AKRAB:~# iptables -nvL FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       10.20.0.2            0.0.0.0/0            /* Accept to forward Fuel DashBoard return traffic */ tcp spt:8443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.20.0.2            /* Accept to forward Fuel DashBoard traffic */ tcp dpt:8443
```

And

```
root@AKRAB:~# iptables -t nat -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 73 packets, 6145 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   18   912 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443 /* redirect pkts to virtual machine */ to:10.20.0.2:8443

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 73 packets, 6145 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 759 packets, 47828 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 759 packets, 47828 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      vboxnet0  0.0.0.0/0            10.20.0.2            /* NAT the src ip */
```

Comment: If you do "iptables -nvL FORWARD" and "iptables -t nat -nvL" you see that the rule are matched? (in the first column you have the packets count). Have you enabled the ip forward?

Comment: Thanks for reply. See my edit for outputs. I think I missunderstood something in the tutorial I've got. Just do a monkey-like-copy-paste with value changes. Can you check it? And yes, the port value actualy is 8443.

Comment: Huh? Ip forwarding? nop. I just done the 3 lines of code in my "Tried this with no success:" area.

Comment: After `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` now I've got a `400 Bad Request - The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port - nginx` error... Now `iptables -nvL FORWARD` is showing some packets values!!

Comment: "400 Bad Request - The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" means that you have called the URL with http instead of https

Comment: Bingo! God bless you son! Try to put IP forwarding tip as an answer so I can accept... NOW... how can I make this permanent? Will clean iptables after boot?

Comment: For the ip foward you can edit "/etc/sysclt.conf" there is the parameter "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" commented

Comment: For future reference, if you would like to have your Question migrated to another site, flag it for moderator attention. That way you don't end up with cross-posts.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller : Thanks for the advice. How could a "port forwarding" topic be "offtopic" in a UNIX site?

Comment: The subject is on-topic, but posting the question in multiple places is not. See the wording of the notice.

Comment: Should it not be "closed as Cross-posting" ? This is the post that actualy solved the question while the other one still opened and unsolved. can we close the other and open this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iptables rules seems to be ok but probably you missed to enable the ip forward, try with:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

then check if the iptables rules are matched with:

```
iptables -t nat -nvL
iptables -nvL FORWARD
```

Comment: how can I make this permanent? Will clean iptables after boot?

Comment: comment out "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" under /etc/sysclt.conf about iptables yes also the rule are flushed at boot

Comment: There is no `/etc/sysclt.conf` file in my Ubuntu 14.04. Why the rules will be gone after boot? I need to recreate them every time I boot my system?

Comment: sorry I have done a typo! the file is /etc/sysctl.conf :) about iptables you can follow this http://askubuntu.com/questions/66890/how-can-i-make-a-specific-set-of-iptables-rules-permanent

Comment: The file is empty anyway. Must I write this line inside it?

Comment: Strange that the file /etc/sysctl.conf is empty, it should not.. Anyway, yes add this line inside the file

Comment: My mistake... wrong user. There is a `sysctl.conf` file there.

Comment: Even I've solved my problem I still not know what I've done. I think will be useful to explain the 3 rules I used in my iptables. Can you do this?